# FLASK - HTML - requested URL was not found

Tags: html, flask

I'm new to html, i have researched a lot, but cannot solve this issue. I'm sure for you it is trivial, but I stuck.

So
I have a flask webserver. that is the code:
it is so simple, just loading the home.html and I guess the issue will be here somewhere, but I cannot find it.
all html docs are in the same folder, in the templates. the home.html loading nicely, but nothing other. I mean if I change in the return render_template the html it will be loaded, but not throug the webpage by clicking.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')


@app.route('/')
def home():
    template_table = {
        'title': "Home Control System"
    }
    return render_template('home.html', **template_table)

@app.route('/')
def lakas():
    return render_template('lakas.html')


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

this is the home.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/style.css?version=15">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/scripts.js?version=2"></script>
</head>
<body onload="renderTime()">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div style="font-size: 1.5em", style="font-weight: bold">Menü</div>
        <div class="nested_1">
            <div align="right">Home Control System</div>
            <div id="clockDisplay" align="right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="nested_2">
            <a href="overview.html" target="targetframe">Főoldal</a>
            <a href="lakas.html" target="targetframe">Lakás</a>
            <a href="garazs.html" target="targetframe">Garázs</a>
        </div>
        <iframe src="overview.html" name="targetframe" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the folder structure is:

```
main
   static
   templates
       home.html
       lakas.html
       garazs.html
```

and if I simple open the home.html everything works perfectly, I can click on the buttons(Főoldal, Lakás, Garázs)

but, when I run the flask app and I reach that through the IP I have the home page, but 404 for the rest of them. I attach picture about the ok screen and the 404.
[Not found screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3gUP.png)
[OK screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sahU5.png)
What should I change? Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your routes are the same? I'm assuming *lakas* should be its own page so you should change **@app.route('/')** to **@app.route('/lakas')**

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    template_table = {
        'title': "Home Control System"
    }
    return render_template('home.html', **template_table)

@app.route('/')
def lakas():
    return render_template('lakas.html')
```

Change the url in **home.html** to `<a href="{{ url_for('lakas') }}">Lakás</a>`

I think you might be having trouble understanding routes. [An understanding of MVC might help.](https://realpython.com/the-model-view-controller-mvc-paradigm-summarized-with-legos/)